# get object variable name in jquery datatable render function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dto returned from service, I would like to insert the values in the datatable. for custom rendering of values i have used "render" function like below.

```
"columns": [
             { "render": render },
             { "data": "description" },
           ]
```

The function is

```
function render(data, type, row){       
    return "some data...";
}
```

For the above code i would like to check conditions with the object's variable name as

```
obj:{name:"harris",age:"20"}
```

while rendering the function i would like to check whether it is name or age, if the data is name it will return some value. If it is an age it will return some other value.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

```
if(row.name != null){
    // code for name 
}else if(row.age != null){
    // code for age 
}
```

Comment: I would like to check the rendering column. whether it is name or age.

Comment: I didnt get you. you want 1 column in dadatble either Name of age right ??/

Comment: i'm going to call only one render function for all the columns in the table, which  returns data depend upon the column variable type